# MongoDB: $inc right after switched primary

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I perform a sequence of the following steps:

**Step 0**: There is a Replica Set with 3 mongod nodes and one document:

`{_id: 1, value: 5}`

Node [1] is PRIMARY.

**Step 1**: Client have executed the following operation with `writeConcern = 'majority'`:

`collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1}, {$inc: {value: 1}})`

Nodes [1] and [2] have been updated immediately to value 6, while node [3] hasn't yet.

**Step 2**: Due to automatic failover node [3] has become primary.

**Step 3**: Client have executed `$inc` operation again, now on node [3] (while it still didn't receive the updated value):

`collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1}, {$inc: {value: 1}})`

Which guarantees does mongodb provide for this last operation?
Could it fail? Could it update value to something other than 7?

Comment: I wonder how 3 can win election if its oplog is behind 2? In fact its oplog sync target should change long before the election so 3 should get `{$inc: {value: 1}}` entry from 2 before election even starts. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Replication-Internals may worth reading.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks, your link is very useful